# Bash Error - Program errors on the lines with the double semi-colons

Tags: bash

Program errors on the lines with the double semi-colons, stating a Syntax error near unexpected token. Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Enter the access password..."
while
    do
        read INPUT_STRING
            case $INPUT_STRING in   

                    ##CORRECT PASSWORD##                
                    lux)        
                        ls -l -S > directory.txt
                            echo "Enter your username..."
                            read a  
                            sed '1 i\ $a' directory.txt
                        date=`date`
                            sed '2 i\ $date' directory.txt
                        date=
                        echo "The operation has completed successfully"
                    ;;

                    ##INCORRECT PASSWORD##          
                    *)  
                        x=1
                        while [ $x -le 3 ]
                        do
                        echo "Incorrect Password, try again. The program will exit after 3 failed attempts."
                        x=$(( $x + 1 ))
                        sleep 2
                        echo "Enter the access password..."
                        if x=3
                        then exit
                        fi
                    ;;
           esac
done
echo 
echo "Process Complete, Goodbye!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` syntax is messed up. You need a condition between the `while` and the `do`. That's probably screwing up the parsing of the `case` statement.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in your code. You need to provide an expression after `while`.

Right now, you have:

```
while
do
```

and you need to specify the epxression that the `while` keyword will loop on. More specifically, it looks like you just want an infinite loop. If this is true, you need to specify:

```
while true
do
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be lacking a `done` to close the `while` statement in the `*)` case